# Firebird 3 backup by non SYSDBA and non DB owner?

Tags: backup, firebird

Is it possible to create a Firebird 3 user who may do backups of a given database but cannot connect as sysdba and use things like tracing or looking into the environment of all sessions?

Comment: For completeness: I ended up in licensing an encryption plugin for Firebird 3 that also handles gbak. I will store the key on the client side encrypted with the users password. This should make the system quite secure against cyber attacks to the server and hardware theft. At least this is near to the maximum security possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebird 2.5 and higher, you can grant a user the RDB$ADMIN role in a database. This will give that user owner or SYSDBA equivalent rights in that database.

```
GRANT [ROLE] RDB$ADMIN TO username
```

See also [RDB$ADMIN Role](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-security-auth.html#fblangref25-security-rdbadmin) in the Firebird 2.5 language reference.

A user with the RDB$ADMIN role can backup the database, provided the role is explicitly specified (option `-role` or `-ro`).

If you think that granting administrator rights to a user might be too much, consider that a user who can backup and restore a database can essentially do anything to the database. For example change owner on restore, or restore on a different machine where they are SYSDBA make necessary changes like granting privileges, manipulate data, etc and then back that up and restore over the original.

Firebird 4 will introduce an additional privilege `USE_GBAK_UTILITY` which can be use to specifically grant a user to only perform gbak operations. My previous point is an important caveat: a user that can backup and restore can do more than you think.

In other words, allowing a user to backup a database without granting them some form of administrator control over the database is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I need some user who may backup and read the database but not look into others sql as I would like to use encryption in udf functions where I habe to pass the key via sql for filtering, sorting and grouping on the server. The main goal of this is that someone who steals the database or a backup has no access to critical parts of the data. Having a backup and look only user, who has no access to others sessions would improve that concept.

Comment: If you automate the backup, then that is less of a problem. You can let the sysdba define the users and setup a backup process that is executed with sufficient privileges. Then no other 'real person' will need to have access to those credentials.

Comment: Yes that is my current approach. I will make my users aware of the fact that if the it department has access to the sysdba password someone with enough criminal energy could reveal the encryption key, then they have to decide.

Comment: @MichaSchumann Depending on the installed server architecture you might be able to get away with embedded passwordless backup (then you can backup as sysdba or the owner without a password). This requires Classic or SuperClassic, or you need to be able to shutdown the database for a period of time, but again that level of access allows you to do things to the database that could subvert other security controls.

Comment: I advise users to shut down the server, copy the database and restart it. This can be done by it personnel without knowlege of any firebird passwords. And as I store the aes key encrypted with a key generated from user passwords it should not be easy to reveal it if no valid user credentials are known (own user management, not the firebird one)

Answer (score 0):

gbak just connects as regular connection to server and reads data through regular SELECT statements, and put them into a backup file. You need to specify either SYSDBA or database owner's account, because of only these accounts have a full access to all data and metadata of database.

As a solution of your problem you could create a batch file with a gbak command and give to the user only rights to execute this file.

Comment: Thanks. But for this Admins would get access to the sysdba password and could use it to trace sql for example.